Remove seconds from time :00 in XSLT
I am trying to modify code so that it only removes the last :00 from the time stamp (seconds) and not the minutes when the time is e.g. 15:00:00
I currently have
<xsl:variable name="time" select="replace(replace(substring-after($date-time,' '),':',''),'00','')" as="xs:string"/>

It works on the following formatted time/date: 2024-10-17 15:00:00
I'm sure it is something simple with last or tokenize but I'm new to this and working on someone else's code as a starting point.
Currently, this is giving the result of just 15 for the time, instead of 1500.

Your question is not entirely clear.
If you always want to remove the seconds part from your $date-time variable, you can do simply:
<xsl:value-of select="substring($date-time, 1, 16)"/>

If you want to do this only when the seconds part is 00, you can do:
<xsl:value-of select="replace($date-time, ':00$', '')"/>

If you want to extract only the hours and minutes portion, without the : separator, do:
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($date-time, 12, 5), ':', '')"/>


It should be noted that 2024-10-17 15:00:00 is a string, not a valid dateTime. If you had a valid dateTime, you could (and probably should) use the format-dateTime() function to shape it the way you want.
